# Can't move button by itself

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project where I recreate Google Search's page. The submit button should be under the search bar, but whenever I try to move it with css (maybe using margin top or something like that), it brings the whole search bar with itself and stays on the right of the search bar.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            #search {
                border-radius: 25px;
                margin-top: 225px;
                width: 400px;
                height: 40px;
                padding: 5px;
                
            }
            li{
                margin-left: 1000px;
            }
                
            
        </style>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Google Image Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Google Advanced Search</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
       <div>
            <center> 
                <form action="https://www.google.com/search">
                <input id="search" type="text" name="q">
                <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
                </form>
            </center>
       </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried every sort of thing with css, even when I try to do it inline it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to achieve what you'd like. For example, you could apply `display: block` to the submit button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Search</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #search {
      border-radius: 25px;
      margin-top: 225px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    li {
      margin-left: 1000px;
    }
    
    [type="submit"] {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Google Image Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Google Advanced Search</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div>
    <center>
      <form action="https://www.google.com/search">
        <input id="search" type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
      </form>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Or you could apply `display: block` to the input:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Search</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #search {
      display: block;
      border-radius: 25px;
      margin-top: 225px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    li {
      margin-left: 1000px;
    }
  </style>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Google Image Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Google Advanced Search</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div>
    <center>
      <form action="https://www.google.com/search">
        <input id="search" type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
      </form>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Or you could create a vertical flex layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Search</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    #search {
      border-radius: 25px;
      margin-top: 225px;
      width: 400px;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    li {
      margin-left: 1000px;
    }
    
    form {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Google Image Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Google Advanced Search</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div>
    <center>
      <form action="https://www.google.com/search">
        <input id="search" type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
      </form>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so so much. I don't really understand what a vertical flex layout is though. And, in your opinion, what's the best solution?

Comment: I'd go for applying `display: block` on one (or both) elements.